# Strange type inferencе with RankNTypes extension

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to experiment with System-F types in Haskell and have implemented Church encoding of natural numbers via `type`.

When loading this code

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

type CNat = forall t . (t -> t) -> (t -> t)

c0 :: CNat
c0 _ x = x

type CPair a b = forall t . (a -> b -> t) -> t

cpair :: a -> b -> CPair a b
cpair a b f = f a b

-- pair3 :: CPair CNat String
pair3 = cpair c0 "hello"
```

into ghci 7.8.2 I get a warning:

```
λ: :l test.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )

test.hs:29:1: Warning:
    Top-level binding with no type signature:
      pair3 :: forall t t1.
               (((t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1) -> [Char] -> t) -> t
Ok, modules loaded: Main.
λ:
```

The question is, shouldn't the type be

```
pair3 :: forall t.
      ((forall t1. (t1 -> t1) -> t1 -> t1) -> [Char] -> t) -> t
```

?

**UPD:** A simpler example is provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But is there any way to specify my type for it so that when
>   I specify it explicitly (uncomment the line in my code), the compiler
>   would not infer it but just check the provided type? Now I am getting
>   error

If you want to instantiate the type variables `a,b` occurring in the type of `cpair`, you can add the following explicit annotation.

```
pair3 :: CPair CNat String
pair3 = (cpair :: CNat -> String -> CPair CNat String) c0 "hello"
```

Without that, `cpair` is only instantiated at monomorphic types, I believe.

Answer (score 10):

That's a perfectly good type for it... but it's not the type Hindley-Milner gives it. HM *always* infers a rank-1 type. Inferring rank-2 types is actually decidable, I believe, but GHC doesn't even try.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Thank you.  But is there any way to specify my type for it so that when I specify it explicitly (uncomment the line in my code), the compiler would not infer it but just check the provided type?  Now I am getting error.

Comment: According to the article "Introduction to type theory" by Herman Geuvers, p.37-38, the Type Checking Problem for System F à la Curry is equivalent to Type assignment problem (and is undecidable).  Probably that is why there is not point in specifying the desired type -- haskell would not be able to check it either.

Comment: Instead, as chi suggested, I should specify the type of subexpression and cound on Hindley-Miller to infer the type of the whole expression.

Comment: See also: [ImpredicativeTypes](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Impredicative_types)