# Is it possible to implement addition on typed Church numerals using iterated incrementation?

Tags: haskell, types, lambda-calculus, higher-rank-types, church-encoding

I can't find a way to define addition as repeated incrementation, despite this being possible in an untyped language. Here is my code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
type Church = forall a . (a -> a) -> (a -> a)

zero :: Church
zero = \f -> id

inc :: Church -> Church
inc n = \f -> f . n f

-- This version of addition works
add1 :: Church -> Church -> Church
add1 n m = \f -> n f . m f

-- This version gives me a compilation error
add2 :: Church -> Church -> Church
add2 n m = n inc m
```

The compilation error I get for `add2` is

```
Couldn't match type `forall a1. (a1 -> a1) -> a1 -> a1'
                  with `(a -> a) -> a -> a'
    Expected type: ((a -> a) -> a -> a) -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
      Actual type: Church -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
    In the first argument of `n', namely `inc'
    In the expression: n inc m
    In an equation for `add2': add2 n m = n inc m
```

Why is this an error? Isn't `Church` a synonym for that `((a->a) -> a -> a)` ?

Comment: You might also like [this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23532659/791604).

Comment: For actual use, I recommend `newtype` instead of type synonyms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not get your code to type, no matter what extra type annotations I added, although it's possible I was not clever enough. (I also tried adding `ImpredicativeTypes`.)
I think the problem here is that in the definition

```
type Church = forall a. (a -> a) -> (a -> a)
```

`a` can only be instantiated with a rank-0 type (i.e. without foralls inside), which `Church` itself isn't. So you cannot apply a Church numeral defined this way to your `inc`.

However, there is a relatively simple workaround that is slightly verbose but makes everything work nicely otherwise: make `Church` into a newtype instead of a type, so that it can be treated as monomorphic from the outside.  The following all works:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
newtype Church = Church { runChurch :: forall a . (a -> a) -> (a -> a) }

zero :: Church
zero = Church (\f -> id)

inc :: Church -> Church
inc n = Church (\f -> f . runChurch n f)

add2 :: Church -> Church -> Church
add2 n = runChurch n inc
```

Comment: I think monomorphic is not the right word; `a` can only be instantiated with a _rank-0_ type.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I see. I've been thinking of the terms as almost synonyms, although I guess it's not truly monomorphic if it still contains a type variable.